# Perl Regex return named groups in capture Group one

Tags: regex, perl

I try to get a regex which returns the match in the first capture group.

The Application where I put the regex in can only use the first capture Group.

Each regex on it's own is working, but i can't combine these two in a way that the output is always in the first capture group

Input 1:

```
Event: Started Flapping
```

Regex 1:

```
^Event: (\S+ Flapping)
```

Output 1:

```
Started Flapping
```

Input 2:

```
Event: CRIT -> OK
```

Regex 2:

```
^Event:\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+(\S+)
```

Ouput 2:

```
OK
```

The Regex i tried
`(?:^Event:\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+(?P<service>\S+)$|^Event: (?P<flap>Started Flapping)|((?P=service)|(?P=flap)))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [**branch reset group**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html):

```
^Event:\s+(?|\S+\s+\S+\s+(\S+)|(Started Flapping))$
# or, to factor in \S+\s+:
^Event:\s+(?|(?:\S+\s+){2}(\S+)|(Started Flapping))$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kATkBM/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `Event:` - a fixed string
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(?|` - start of a branch reset group:

  - `\S+\s+\S+\s+` - two occurrences of one or more non-whitespaces followed with one or more whitespaces
  - `(\S+)` - Group 1: one or more non-whitespaces
- `|` - or

  - `(Started Flapping)` - Group 1: `Started Flapping` fixed string
- `)` - end of the branch reset group
- `$` - end of string.